# How many concrete methods can an interface have (JDK 7 and below)

Tags: java

How many concrete methods can an interface have (JDK 7 and below)
JDK 7 and below. I have tried to research everywhere but can not find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces cannot have any concrete methods. If you need the ability to have abstract method definitions and concrete methods then you should use an abstract class.

Note: This is only true for JDK 7 and lower. JDK 8 includes default methods which provide concrete methods in interfaces. (Thanks EJoshuaS)

Comment: This is only partially correct. Java 8 has [default methods](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/default-methods-java/), which is basically what the OP is asking. Java 7 and lower does not.

Comment: thank you. so an interface can not contain concrete methods?

Comment: @GulfamChoudhary Yes, in JDK 7 and below an interface cannot contain concrete methods.

Comment: You should edit your answer to specify that that's true for Java 7, because this answer is incorrect for Java 8 and higher.

Comment: @EJoshuaS I'll add a clarification, but I think that distinction is unnecessary because the question specified JDK 7 and lower.

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 has [default methods](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/default-methods-java/), which is basically what you're asking about. However, Java 7 and lower cannot have that; it can only specify the mandatory method signatures. So, the answer to your question is "none at all - Java 7 doesn't allow that."

There is not, as far as I know, a hard limit on the number of methods that an interface can have. That being said, if you're even asking about this, you likely have a design problem because you're probably considering making your interface too large. A good rule of thumb is that, if you're describing what an interface is for, you shouldn't have to use the word "and" - if you find that you do, you should refactor to split it into multiple interfaces.

**Edit:** Evidently the maximum is 65535, but there’s no reason that you should ever have anything close to that.